# CSS animation not working on iPad Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, css-animations

I am using some CSS animations in our new website. All animations are working, except a hover slide that we have. The slide is created by this bit of CSS:

```
.portfol io-item {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.portfolio-item img {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    transition: transform 0.4s;
    z-index:500;
}

.portfolio-item:hover img {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(100px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(100px,0,0);
}

.portfolio-item:hover .caption {
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(192px,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(192px,0,0);
}

.portfolio-item .shadow {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#666666;
    opacity:0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

.portfolio-item:hover .shadow {
    opacity:0.75;
    filter:alpha(opacity=75);
}


.portfolio-item .button {
    border: 1px solid #e2e2e2;
    font-family: robotolight_italic;
    font-size: 19px;
    color: #cacaca;
    line-height: 38px;
    padding: 0 34px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.portfolio-item .button:hover {
    color:#ffffff;
    z-index:1;
}

.portfolio-item .button:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    z-index:-1;
    width: 101%;
    height: 0;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    background: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
    transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}

.portfolio-item .button:hover:after {
    height: 75%;
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    background:#1F82C5;
}

.portfolio-item .button:active:after {
    height: 130%;
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
}
```

And my HTML:

```
    <div class="portfolio-item" style="height:564px;width:270px">
        <div class="shadow"></div>
        <div class="caption" style="height:564px">
            <h3><span>Test Element</span></h3>
            <div class="category">Category: <br><span>Some Categories</span></div>
            <a class="button" id="7">Details</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Basically a slide to the right, with an overlay sliding over it and a bit of a fade on the original image. It works on all browsers: Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari, IE9+ but it does not work on Safari mobile. All other mobile browsers handle this fine.

At first I thought it was some clash, so I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/90wjkbqb/) that I opened on the iPad, however it still didn't work. The iPad runs Safari 7.0.

I have no idea what is wrong. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: And how would you like to make hover on tablet? -.-

Comment: If I tap the item on any other mobile device, it triggers the hover effect.

Comment: There are some devices that detects your finger in the screen's proximity but that's a rare behaviour. A hover effect is mostly out of discussion on touch screen devices.